# Angular date range filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

I was wondering if anyone could help me.  I'm currently trying to get a date filter to work in Angular.  I could be going about this completely the wrong way but just thought I would ask.

I currently have an ng-repeat looping through an array of objects.  My objects have the following fields: title, sentBy and recevied.  Received is in UTC format and my filter basically takes two inputs also in utc format for start and end date.  The filter then checked if the received is greater than or equal to to start date or less than or equal to the end date.  My issue is that the input to the filter is the input of the whole object.  Im not sure how to access the received field of the object within the filter to do the comparrison.  I tried input.received but it didnt seem to work. heres a sample of my code.

```
.filter('dateRange', function(){

return function(input, startDate, endDate) {

    if(input.received >= startDate && input <= endDate){
        return input;
    }

};
```

})

As I say I could be going about this completely wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: 
my html code is as simple as below:

```
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages | dateRange: startDate : endDate " >
```

Comment: Please provide more code: you should add the HTML in which you pass the filter to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. You need to compare the time.

```
.filter('dateRange', function(){

    return function(input, startDate, endDate) {
       angular.forEach(input, function(obj){

        if(obj.received.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() && obj.received.getTime() <= endDate.getTime())   {
            return obj;
        }
       });

    };
});

<div ng-bind="messages | dateRange: startDate : endDate " ></div>
   or
<div> {{messages | dateRange: startDate : endDate }}</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately when trying to access input.received I get the error input.received is undefined, maybe I'm doing something stupid.  Thanks for the reply though.  Since its an array of objects do I need to get the index of the array somehow?

Comment: Just tested, I need the array index it seems, now I need some method of incrementing or passing the index in.  Will play about with it for a bit and see if I can come up with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Bah dont seem to be able to figure out how to pass the appropriate index of the array in via the filter, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your code the filter is working on *messages* array, that means the first argument (*input*) is the array, and the return type has to be an array too. Have a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Your code should be something like that:

```
 <div ng-repeat="message in messages | dateRange: startDate : endDate" >
```

Your filter is:

```
.filter('dateRange', function() {
   return function(input, startDate, endDate) {

      var retArray = [];

      angular.forEach(input, function(obj){
        var receivedDate = obj.received;

        if(receivedDate >= startDate && receivedDate <= endDate) {
            retArray.push(obj);         
        }
      });

      return retArray;
   };
});
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6lYWj?p=preview).